# Android Library & CI

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-gradle-plugin, gitlab-ci, gradlew

I want to run tests in my `android library` project from Gitlab CI:
My .`gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
before_script:
  - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
  - export GRADLE_HOME="/opt/gradle"
  - export PATH="/opt/gradle/bin:$PATH"
  - export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/tools
  - export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
build:
  script:
    - gradle clean build
```

I get

> Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.

What I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the next into my android library **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```